# Can I suppress the taskbar when running a java application?

Tags: java, windows, taskbar

I'm trying to have a java application run in the background of fullscreen applications like a media player or a PC game, but every time my java popup comes to the front it also shows the windows taskbar. Is there a way to suppress this from showing up whenever I run my application or change window focus?

Comment: Try the snippet from this example http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.awt/screen_FullWin.html